# Weird problem with 500 Internal server error " System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. "

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am currently working on the functionality of user liking items in the store. My goal is to allow a user to like a product and add it to the list of liked products, one user can like multiple products, and each product can be liked by multiple users. However, the problem is that when I test the request in Postman I get a 500 Internal server error - "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format". The problem is that the value of the string variable cannot be converted to an integer in the ClaimsPrinciple class, althought I think I am doing it correctly? I did some coding and debugging.  Do I need to return something in the controller? User is logged in but I get userId = 0 and product null however there are user and product with such Id in the database. I am so confused. Any suggestion's how to overcome that?

[image]
[image]

```
//Here are product and user entity

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public List<Product> LikedProducts { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
}

public static class ClaimPrincipleExtensions
{
    public static string GetUsername(this ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        return user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
    }

    public static int GetUserId(this ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        return int.Parse(user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value); // Im getting an exception here
    }
}

// Here is my controller
    [HttpPost("add-to-favorites/{productId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddToFavorites(int productId)
    {
        var userId = User.GetUserId();

        var product = await _productRepository.GetProductById(productId);

        var user = await _userRepository.GetUser(userId);

        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (product.UserId == userId)
        {
            return BadRequest("You cannot like your own product.");
        }

        user.LikedProducts.Add(product);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the details of what your request looks like?

Comment: Before getting the user id, is the user object populated with a valid user?

Comment: `int.Parse(user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value);` Seems, like at least one user has a `Value` for `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` that cannot be parsed to an int ... Separate this in two steps `var val = user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value; return int.Parse(val);` and set a breakpoint at the second. So you'll see, what `val` actually is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format from an int.Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61448267/system-formatexception-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-from-an-int-par)

Comment: @derpirscher I did your sugesstion, I have separated this into two steps, and debugged. val has a value val [string]: "saymon" - which is logged user's username.

Comment: So, how would you parse `"saymon"` into an int? You are probably querying the wrong property ...

Comment: You can't.  Since it is a key maybe you need to get the hash value using method .GetHashCode()

Comment: @jdweng You don't say ... And why would one go for the hash of the username, when there is a `userid` property available?

Comment: How do you login the user with claims? If you use default Identity and custom the IdentityUser with int id, you can convert to int successfully. It seems you are not familiar with C#? If it is string "1", of course can be converted to int, but your value here is `saymon` which is not possible to convert to int type.

Answer (score 0):

You send to not be passing the parameters to the AddToFavorites action. The ClaimsPrincipal doesn't seem to have much to do with it. What does your Postman request look like?
Make sure you POST as url encoded form values.

Comment: I've supplemented my post with a screen shot of the postman.